# Why is the "download_link" result from Compose for MySQL API set to "true" instead of a url?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, compose-db

With the Compose for MySQL api, when I query for the details of a logfile, a download link is not provided as it should, per the docs at https://www.compose.com/articles/the-ibm-cloud-compose-api/. The value for "download_link" is instead "true".

A result example:

```
{
  "id": "...",
  "capsule_id": "...",
  "deployment_id": "...",
  "file_size": 106864,
  "status": "success",
  "date": "2019-06-14",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "name": "haproxy1114.log-2019-06-14.gz",
  "download_link": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a support ticket with IBM and they resolved the issue; the value of 'download_link' is now an actual hyperlink.